Add author and data in footer in Quarto to Pdf with .tex
From a Header and footer in quarto qmd to pdf I learned it is best to use  scrlayer-scrpage when wanting a footer:
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Me"
date: "this day"
format: 
  pdf:
    include-in-header: 
      text: |
        \usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
        \rohead{Header text}
        \lofoot{Footer text}  
---

How could I add the author and the date to the footer (left-aligned)? And what would I add to have the pagenummber at footer in bottom-right? Thanks!
I am looking for some code that extracts the author and the date from the YAML, my final code will be living in a template.tex file.

Have you tried this?

I didn't before. Thanks. Unfortunately it clashes with other stuff.

Try the following,
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Me"
date: today
format: 
  pdf:
    include-in-header: 
      text: |
        \usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
        \usepackage{titling}
        \clearpairofpagestyles
        \lefoot*{\theauthor\hspace{2mm}\thedate}  
        \lofoot*{\theauthor\hspace{2mm}\thedate}
        \refoot*{\pagemark}
        \rofoot*{\pagemark}
---


```{r}
#| echo: false
#| results: asis
cat(stringi::stri_rand_lipsum(20), sep = "\n\n")
```

To understand how \lefoot, \lofoot, \refoot, \rofoot works, please read through the KOMA-Script manual, from p.265 to p.268.

Thanks Shafee, it worked! First I encountered some difficulties regarding not being able to finding titling.sty, but after reinstalling tinytex with tinytex::reinstall_tinytex(), it worked.
